# Chart.js on web-app

Tags: chart.js

I have implemented Chart.js on my web-app but I need add some functionality:

- Put a value inside each column of the bar chart
- Choose the position of the tooltip
- Automatically toggle the tooltip when the chartcomes out

Is it possible to do these things? Thanks in advance

L.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code in your var option

```
{
tooltipTemplate: "<%= value %>",
onAnimationComplete: function(){
                            this.showTooltip(this.segments, true);},
                        tooltipEvents: [],
                        showTooltips: true
}
```

this code in arguments of charts(near option).->

```
{ tooltipTemplate : "<%if (label){%><%=label%>: <%}%><%= value %>%", animateRotate: true }
```

And This one in anywhere in script tag

```
legend(document.getElementById("legendCont"), Data);
```